# Configure esplora to point to the bitcoind servers ip address

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, bitcoind

I have 2 servers running:

1. Ubuntu 18.04 running bitcoind daemon (v0.18.1 full blockchain synchronized)
2. Ubuntu 18.04 running esplora (the local single page website works, but it has no data from the local blockchain)

Both servers are on the same network.

How do I configure esplora to point to the ip address of the bitcoind server?  I would like to use my own full blockchain and explore it with esplora, aka a personal blockchain explorer.

The bitcoind server is already configured and working.  So the only part remaining (I think) is to configure esplora to point to the bitcoind server.  I can't find any clear instructions on how to do that.